# Execute mocha tests through proxy or not with grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js

I'd like to configure my mocha tests to be performed behind a proxy or not.
For example,

```
grunt test
```

would execute the tests I have defined in my test folder on localhost (no proxy).

And

```
export http_proxy=PROXY:PORT
grunt test mywebsite.com
```

would execute the tests but through a proxy.

Is that possible?